# MVC 3 AJAX Post, List filled with Objects, but Objects Properties are Empty

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, model-binding

I have the following problem:

On a Button-Click I POST some data to the server.
My controller Action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Accept(List<MyViewModel> entries)
{
    //here entries HAS 2 MyViewModel-Instances in it.
    //The entries are not null, but the values of the instances are!
    //entries[0].ParamA is null
}
```

Where the MyViewModel looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string ParamA { get; set; }
    public string ParamB { get; set; }
}
```

And the AJAX-Call is the follwing:

```
var myEntries = { entries: [{ ParamA: "A", ParamB: "B" }, { ParamA: "C", ParamB: "D" }] };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    data: myEntries,
    dataType: 'text' });
```

**What i already tried to do:**

- Changed dataType to 'json'
- used: traditional: true
- tried var myEntries = JSON.stringify(...);
- tried var myEntries = { entries : [JSON.stringify({ ... }), JSON.stringify({ ... })] };
- same as above, but with jQuery.param(..., true);
- Use of IEnumerable or MyViewModel[] instead of list.
- ANY combination of the above

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very, very much in advance for helping me!

**EDIT**

My (Razor)View is not interesting at this moment as it has nothing to do with anything. I am NOT using any of the HTML.TextBoxFor (or similiar) Methods to fill the myEntries-Variable. It is actually filled dynamically (because there are many many conditions).
For the sake of the question (and my own testing) i hard-coded the variable. :)

Comment: Can you post code of your (Razor)view?

Comment: My View has nothing interesting in it. I clearified it in my question. See the EDIT-Section

Comment: I have the answer! I'll post as soon as I can (have to wait 8 hours...)

Comment: @AndrewF: See my answer below. (I can mark it as accepted tomorrow ;))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With your answer and the use of `JSON.stringify` method it works for me

```
var myEntries = { entries: [{ ParamA: "A", ParamB: "B" }, 
                            { ParamA: "C", ParamB: "D" }] };

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/{controller}/{action}',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(myEntries),
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
```

Comment: It seems I forgot to say that I used JSON.stringify too. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem of my list being populated but all their properties were empty. I was using $.Post(..) which I thought would just be a wrapper around $.ajax(type:'POST', ...), but there must be some difference as using the $.ajax example above works great.

Comment: I just want to emphasize, that setup of contentType to 'application/json' is critical. In my case it just didn't work without this!

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer!

jQuery can be confusing at times.

dataType is the parameter which specifies what you want to get BACK from the server.
contentType is the paremeter which specifies what you SEND TO the server.

So from the example above it works if you add:

contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

in the AJAX-call.

Answer (score 1):

Just to compliment the answer on how to create the list that will be post back to the controller. That is because you don't need to wrap the array with the name of the list. It looks ugly and is not manageable using built in functions.  This example is here to show how to post back JSON that MVC will understand and interpret as a List of. (But even if the Array is wrapped it still works but that is static content and difficult to manage)

This example used jQuery's sortable plugin. I want to post the entire list model back with the new ordering  indexes to save in the database.

```
update: function (event, ui) {

 img = { key: 0, order: 0, url: '' }; //Single image model on server
 imgs = new Array(); //An array to hold the image models.

 //Iterate through all the List Items and build my model based on the data.
 $('#UploaderThumbnails li').each(function (e) {
      img.key = $(this).data('key');  //Primary Key
      img.order = $(this).index();  //Order index
      imgs.push(img); //put into "list" array
 });

 //And what is in the answer - this works really great
 $.ajax({
     url: '/Image/UpdateOrder',
     data: JSON.stringify(imgs),
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  });

}
```

And my MVC controller is as simple as ...

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UpdateOrder(List<Models.Image> images)
  {
     //Images at this point is a proper C# List of Images! :) Easy!

      return Content("");
  }
```

Comment: This worked for me. And just to reiterate, don't forget that application/json content type!