# Send array from view to controller using ajax (it counts array items but values null) mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i want to send array from my view to controller using ajax 
so i use following code in my view jquery

```
        $("#mainBody").on("click", "#newAdd", function () {

            var myobjects = new Array();
            myobjects[0]={ "Name": "Ali", "job": "Developer" };
            myobjects[1] = { "Name": "Mohamed", "job": "Tester" };
            myobjects[2] = { "Name": "AHmed", "job": "Manager" };


            var parameters = { "myobjects": myobjects };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("NewAdd")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: parameters,
                async: false,
                success: function () {
                    alert("Hi");
                }
            });


        });
```

and my controller like that :

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult NewAdd(employee[] myobjects)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true,data="ok" });
        }
```

my employee model like that :

```
public class employee { public string Name { get; set; } public string job { get; set; } }
```

the problem is when i debug i found my controller actiobn count myobjects as three but content of each one is null

Comment: Start with updating `data: JSON.stringify(parameters)`.  You've specified JSON as the datatype, however by default AJAX will convert Javascript object to QueryString Parameters not JSON.  Additionally I would recommend `contentType: 'application/json'`.

Comment: It shouldn't matter either way.

Comment: The problem is the default array serialization in AJAX will create `myobjects[0][Name]=Ali`.  The model binder should confuse `[Name]` for an array and not a property, thus the array is populated but the properties are not.  The correct value for the model binder should be `myobjects[0].Name=Ali`.  The only way I know how to correct this is to use JSON instead of QueryString.  [Example 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101896/mvc-3-ajax-post-list-filled-with-objects-but-objects-properties-are-empty)